# load content from external file javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load div which's id equal to id `('#content'+divId)`
for example button's `id=1`   and it must load content from `file.php` which div id equal to content_1 and button's `id=2`   and it must load content from `file.php` which div id equal to content_2. both content loads form the same file and  it must be shown in different divs.

here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {         
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){

        var toLoad = hash+'.html #content_low'+divId;
        $('#content'+divId).load(toLoad);
        alert(divId);
    }                                           
});

$('#nav li a').click(function(){
    divId = $(this).parents('li').attr('id');   
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+'#content_low'+divId;
    alert(divId);
    $('#content'+divId).slideUp('normal',loadContent).delay(200);
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-$(this).attr('href').length);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content'+divId).load(toLoad,showNewContent)
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content'+divId).delay(700).slideDown($('#content'+divId).height());

    }
    return false;

});
});
```

here is html

```
<ul id="nav" class="marketlist"><li id="1" class="market twobox">
<a href="external_file.php"><img src="img/projects/1.jpg" class="items" alt="" /></a>
</li><li id="2" class="market"> 
<a href="external_file.php"><img src="img/projects/1.jpg" class="items" alt="" /></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The code and question is verry messy and unclear...

Comment: now it loads all the div inside of external file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but your div's dont contain any id. so there will never be a match.

I would generate the div's or LI's by code.

```
$('#nav').append("<li id='#content'" + divId + "'></li>");
```